# Adding url to mysql row in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to add a url to a text row in mysql using python and the MySQLdb library, but when I run my code it says there is an error in my sql syntax. Can you tell me what im doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
connection = mdb.connect("Localhost", "root", "", "db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
url = mdb.escape_string("http://www.google.com")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO index(url) VALUES(%s)""", (url,))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "E:\prospector\webworker.py", line 77, in run
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO index(url) VALUES('%s')", (url_t,))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index(url) VALUES('http://www.google.com/')' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem like this:

```
mysql> create table `index` (url varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into index(url) values ('http://www.google.com');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index(url) values ('http://www.google.com')' at line 1

mysql> insert into `index`(url) values ('http://www.google.com');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

---

`index` is a keyword in MySQL. Your life will be easier if you do not use it as a table name.
However, if you really want to, you can use it, but then you have to quote it:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `index`(url) VALUES(%s)""", (url,))
```

---

PS: No need to call

```
url = mdb.escape_string("http://www.google.com")
```

MySQLdb will do that automatically for you when you call

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO index(url) VALUES(%s)""", (url,))
```

In fact, since `cursor.execute` calls `mdb.escape_string` for you, doing it yourself could cause undesired values to be inserted into the database depending on the value of `url`:

```
In [105]: MySQLdb.escape_string("That's all folks")
Out[105]: "That\\'s all folks"

In [106]: MySQLdb.escape_string(MySQLdb.escape_string("That's all folks"))
Out[106]: "That\\\\\\'s all folks"
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I should've known. Thank you so much :)