# How to get image in server side using python and store value of image in varbinary format in sql

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to get value of image to server side using python and want to store it in sql db. I need to store image value as varbinary format in sql server. How do I do that? If anybody has an idea please share them with me.

Comment: what you mean about value of image ? did you mean a matrix of pixels value ?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to store the `url` you can do it with `mysql shell` or python code  like this :

shell:

```
mysql> create table `index` (url varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into `index`(url) values ('http://www.google.com');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Writers")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
                 Name VARCHAR(25))")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Jack London')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Honore de Balzac')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Emile Zola')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Truman Capote')")
```

for more informations see this links:

[zetcode](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/)

[stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042013/adding-url-to-mysql-row-in-python)